# reflection not printing constructor name in a class

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to get the constructor name printed using reflection however its skipping the loop which is for printing the name of loop.

```
package reflection.com;

import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

abstract interface FirstInterface {

    void showFirstInterface();
}

abstract interface SecondInterface {

    void showSecondInterface();
}

abstract interface ThirdInterface {

    void showThirdinterface();
}

class SuperClass implements FirstInterface {

    int x, y, z;

    SuperClass() {
        System.out.println("Super Class Constructor...");
    }

    public void showFirstInterface() {
        System.out.println("In class Super Class....");
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass implements SecondInterface, ThirdInterface {

    int a, b, c;

    SubClass() {
    }

    SubClass(int a, int b, int c) {

    }

    public void showSecondInterface() {
        System.out.println("In class Sub Class implementing Second Interface...");

    }

    public void showThirdinterface() {

        System.out.println("In class Sub Class implementing Third Interface...");
    }
}

class ReflectionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class class1 = SubClass.class;
        int modifier = class1.getModifiers();
        Class superClass = class1.getSuperclass();
        Class[] interfaces = class1.getInterfaces();
        Constructor[] constructor = class1.getConstructors();
        Method[] method = class1.getMethods();
        Field[] field = class1.getFields();
        System.out.println("Fully Qualified Class Name..." + class1.getName());
        System.out.println("Class Name..." + class1.getSimpleName());
        System.out.println("Class Modifier...." + Modifier.isPublic(modifier));
        System.out.println("Class Super Class....." + superClass.getName());
        System.out.println("Following are the interfaces.....");
        for (int i = 0; i < interfaces.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(interfaces[i].getName());
        }
        System.out.println("Following are the Constructor.....");
        for (int i = 0; i < constructor.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(constructor[i].getName());
        }
        System.out.println("Following are the Fields.....");
        for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(field[i].getName());
        }
        System.out.println("Following are the Methods.....");
        for (int i = 0; i < method.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(method[i].getName());
        }
        for (Method method1 : method) {
            System.out.println(method1.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to debug the application but no use its not going into the for loop itself.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I don't see a loop here..

Comment: A *lot* of your code is completely irrelevant to the question - as well as being incredibly poorly formatted. Please reduce your question to a *short* but complete program which *only* includes code relevant to your problem, and then show the actual output and the expected output.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation for [`getConstructors()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors%28%29) [emphasis mine]:

> Returns an array containing `Constructor` objects reflecting all the **public** constructors of the class represented by this `Class` object.

Your class doesn't have any public constructors. The two constructors are package-private:

```
public class SubClass ... {
    SubClass() {}
    SubClass(int a, int b, int c) {}
```

Comment: so if the constructor are package private...then how can we get the constructors name

Comment: @Deepak_Sharma: Please post this as a separate question.